# regular expression to match C function call over multiple lines

Tags: regex

I am struggling to put together a regex to match a function call like following:

```
funcname (...(..
    ...)..(..(...
    )...)..)
```

so the function can have multiple bracketed parameters spread over multiple lines.

The dots can be anything else appart from '(' or ')'.

I would use the regex with sed or grep.

Thanks,
Risto

Comment: for what reason you want to use regex? and what have you tried?

Comment: Well I am on Linux and have already some bash scripts that work together on the same cause. What could you suggest?

Comment: write your own simple parser. These are nested symbols, so, don't use regex for it. Or, you must know, which symbol (sequence) will go after last `)`

Comment: OK, I went on with writing a parser in bash. Seems to do the job. Thanks to all for taking part in this thread!

Comment: dump ast might help nowdays. ```clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only test.cc```

Answer (score 0):

As C is an [irregular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) you may need a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) for that. The problem you will have is working out when all the open brackets are closed again. You can do some fairly strange things with C. For example you can have a parameter that is a function definition in its own right. For example consider in the following program how you would distinguish between a(), b(), c(), d(), e(), f() and g()?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define f(c) c;

char a()
{
    return f('z');
}

/*
A function in a comment.
char b()
{
    return 'y';
}
*/

char c(char d()) 
{
    return d(); 
}

#if 0
This code is not included
char g()
{
    return 'v';
}
#endif

void main()
{
    printf ("A function in a string: char e() { return 'x'; }\n");
    printf ("The result from passing a to c: %c\n", c(a));
    printf ("Press enter to exit");
    getchar();
}
```

I have seen many attempts to do this kind of thing with Regular Expressions but most of them end up with [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) issues.

Comment: Function pointers really don't look like that...proper syntax would be `char tst(char (*c)(void))`.

Also this looks like c++, there's no namespaces in C, functions with no parameters must be declared with `void` parameters, and main must return an `int`

Comment: It would be news to me that you can have a function declaration *in the parameter list* o.ô

Comment: @WoodrowDouglass I've updated the example with a more C version. I have compiled and run this using Visual Studio with the /TC compiler switch.

Answer (score 0):

So, I went on writing this simple parser in bash. It is not perfect but can serve as a starting point. For example it cannot distinguish if a function call is commented out or not, etc.

```
while read file; do
    linenum=0
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        (( linenum++ ))
        if [ $fmatch -eq 0 ]; then
            if [[ ! $line =~ $funcname ]]; then
                continue
            fi
            linenummatch=$linenum
            fmatch=1
            fstripped=0
            openbracket=0
            closebracket=0
            spacenum=0
        fi

        linelen=${#line}
        position=0
        while [ $position -lt $linelen ]; do
            if [ $fstripped -eq 0 ]; then
                subline=${line:$position}
                mlen=`expr "$subline" : "$funcname"`
                if [ $mlen -gt 0 ]; then
                    (( position+=mlen ))
                    resultstr=$funcname
                    fstripped=1
                    continue
                fi
                (( position++ ))
                continue
            fi
            ch=${line:$position:1}

            case $ch in
                '(' )
                    (( openbracket++ ))
                    spacenum=0
                    newresultstr="$resultstr$ch"
                    ;;

                ')' )
                    if [ $openbracket -eq 0 ]; then
                        fmatch=0
                        break
                    fi
                    (( closebracket++ ))
                    spacenum=0
                    newresultstr="$resultstr$ch"
                    if [ $closebracket -eq $openbracket ]; then
                        echo "$file $linenummatch $newresultstr"
                        fmatch=0
                        break
                    fi
                    ;;

                ' ' | '\t' )
                    if [ $spacenum -eq 0 ]; then
                        newresultstr=$resultstr' '
                    fi
                    (( spacenum++ ))
                    ;;

                '\n' )
                    # line feeds are skipped
                    ;;
                * )
                    if [ $openbracket -eq 0 ]; then
                        fmatch=0
                        break
                    fi
                    spacenum=0
                    newresultstr="$resultstr$ch"
                    ;;
            esac
            resultstr=$newresultstr
            (( position++ ))
        done
    done < $file
done < $filelist
```